# Bubble Sorting Program, Works in DM compiler(on windows) & not on GCC(Ubuntu)

Tags: c, gcc, bubble-sort, dm

I made this bubble sort algorithm in C. Its working well in DM, but when executed in gcc, gives me incorrect output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i,j;

void BubbleSort(int*a, int n) //to sort the numbers
{
    int temp;
    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
        for(j=n; j>i;j--)
            if (a[j]<a[j-1])
                {
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j-1];
                    a[j-1]=temp;
                }
}

void Display(int * a, int n) //to display
{
    printf("\nThe sorted numbers are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%d, ",a[i]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    int a[50],n,choice;
    printf("\nEnter no. of elements to sort: (max. 50) ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the numbers : ");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    BubbleSort(a,n);
    Display(a,n);

    return 0;

} //End of main
```

Input:

```
5
2 1 5 3 4
```

DM Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

GCC Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 4,
```

How and why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?  Or printing intermediate values of variables?

Comment: You're accessing the `(n+1)th` element of the array in the loop: `a[j]` is `a[5]` when `j` goes from 5 to `i`. But an array with 5 elements, does not have an index of `5`.

Comment: It is appalling to use global variables `i` and `j` under any circumstances (there are very few reasons to use a single-letter globals), and doubly so when it is just a way of avoiding declaring loop variables.  C99 lets you write:  `for (int i = 0; ...)` etc.

Comment: Oh... Thanks! that was one silly mistake... any idea why it worked on DM though?? :(

Comment: It is also a poor UI that requires you to count the number of items to be sorted before you can enter them.  Computers are good at counting.  (You wouldn't use the Unix `sort` command if you had to tell it how many lines of data were in each file!)

Comment: I'm still a novice, just learning various sorting techniques... was experimenting around, trying to make a comandline tool using makefile... Guess will have to delve deeper.. make it more efficient.. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: `i` and `j` are reasonable names for loop control variables.  Of course I agree they shouldn't be global.  Not all compilers support declarations in `for` loops; an alternative is to declare them local to the function.

Comment: @Keith: I use `i` and `j` all the time; the complaint was not about the names alone, but about using those names with global status.  And I explicitly said C99; if your compiler is not C99, then it won't support the notation.  (Since the question cites GCC on Ubuntu, this isn't an issue, unless you hobble it by forcing C89 modes.)  I forebore to comment on 'they should be `static` so they can't be seen outside this source file'; I also forebore to comment on the unnecessarily large scope for `temp` in the sort function.

Comment: @Jonathan: Sure, I just wanted to make sure those points were clear to the OP; I can imagine him/her misinterpreting your advice by making the variables local *and* giving them unwieldy names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that this works at all is suspect.  You're overstepping the original array on this line:

```
if (a[j]<a[j-1])  // sketchy when j==n
```

You're comparing a value that you haven't initialized so the value at `a[n]` is whatever is there upon initialization.

This line:

```
for(j=n; j>i;j--)
```

should be:

```
for(j=n-1; j>i;j--)
```

Comment: Hey thanks!! That was a logical error...But now i'm trying to figure why it work$ed on Digital Mars compiler!! :/

Comment: @Ashwini: The behavior is undefined, so anything can happen.  Working "correctly" is actually the worst outcome.

Comment: Agree about the "worst outcome" part. Had i not tested it on GCC again, i would have probably never realised the error. Now I know why people usually prefer GCC.

Comment: Interesting. I understand that UB can cause anything, but I am little mystified as to how this bug could cause the described output. There will be an indeterminate value at `a[5]`, but on any system I've ever worked on it'll be *some* value.  That value would either bubble into the output (if it was `<5`) or it wouldn't. I don't see how this particular bug would cause the 'sorted' array to end up as in the question, so I wonder what else is going on that I don't see.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Figured anything yet?? I am still wondering why no random value is showing up...